# How can I share a 'unit of work' between multiple service methods?

Tags: c#, transactions, repository-pattern, autofac, unit-of-work

I'm having an issue implementing the unit of work pattern in an application service that I'm building as part of a prototype. I think I'm either:

> a) Missing something in the capabilities of autofac that I don't know
>   it can do **OR**
>
> b) Misusing the unit of work pattern entirely and need to refactor my
>   service and/or repositories.

Essentially my problem stems from code sharing within my service. Specifically I have a service method called `CreateCustomerAsync(…)` and within that I build a unit of work (wrapping a db connection and beginning a db transaction) and use a repository to insert into a couple of database tables. That works fine until I want to call out from that method (and within the scope of the UOW) to another service method called `AddCustomerToGroupAsync(…)` in order to (within the same UOW) add a customer to a group (adding a row to a link table). `AddCustomerToGroupAsync` itself uses its own unit of work internally in order to make sure its repository actions happen within a DB transaction as well.

At the moment I cant do all that within the same UOW - in fact with the code like that it actually doesn’t work at all, since the inner most UOW is running over a different connection it can't see the customer that has been inserted in the outer transaction yet! I could re-order the code so that the `AddCustomerToGroupAsync` call is outside of the parent UOW but then I lose database integrity.

So - I roughly (this isnt syntactically correct - but representative of the problem I'm facing) something like this:

```
public async Task<int> CreateCustomerAsync(string name, int groupid)
{
    // do some validation etc..

    // NOTE: UnitOfWork and CustomerRepository are scoped to InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope for 'tx'
    using(var scope = this.Container.BeginLifetimeScope("tx"))
    using(var uow = scope.Resolve<UnitOfWork>())
    {
        // NOTE: ResolveRepository is an extension method - the repo is having the uow injected into it
        var customerrepository = uow.ResolveRepository<CustomerRepository>();

        // multiple repository calls all within the same UOW/db transaction
        int newid = await customerrepository.CreateAsync(name);
        await customerrepository.ActivateAsync(newid);

        // here we invoke our seperate service method... and which I would *like* to execute within
        // this same UOW - so if it fails then all of the db statements executed so far get rolled back
        await this.AddCustomerToGroupAsync(newid, groupid);

        uow.Commit();
    }
}

public async Task<bool> AddCustomerToGroupAsync(int customerId, int groupId)
{
    // really here I'd LIKE to resolve the same lifetime scope that was constructed in the parent if it doesnt
    // exist with the tag specified already...
    // if i could do that then I would be able to resolve the *same* unit of work which would be a step forward
    using(var scope = this.Container.BeginLifetimeScope("tx"))
    using (var uow = scope.Resolve<UnitOfWork>())
    {
        var grouprepository = uow.ResolveRepository<GroupRepository>();

        // two repository calls that need to be wrapped in the same UOW/TX
        int linkid = await grouprepository.CreateLinkAsync(customerId, groupId);
        await grouprepository.ActivateAsync(linkid);

        uow.Commit();
    }
}
```

Any pointers to try and achieve this or is my approach fundamentally misguided?

Cheers.

Comment: I would write an overloaded `AddCustomerToGroupAsync` which takes a scope & uow as a parameter. This method would do the grunt work (adding the role - but *not* calling `uow.Commit()`). The method which only takes a customerid and groupid would construct the scope & uow, and handle the uow.Commit(). `CreateCustomerAsync` Would simply call the new method, passing the scope and unit of work.

Comment: That is definitely a valid approach - but somehow feels 'wrong' to me if you know what I mean? It seems to expose internals of the call and is extra boiler plate that is no doubt going to increase over time. Do you think theres any way to achieve this using DI?

Comment: You should not have to create a new `Lifetimescope`. `LifetimeScope` should be created at the beginning of your work (for example at the beggining of the HTTP request). For a MVC or Web API project, a new scope is automatically created by the Autofac integration package.

Comment: @KieranBenton I'm of the opinion that methods such as `AddCustomerToGroupAsync` should *always* take a unit of work - and its not an implementation detail. These methods are of the assumption that they should immediately persist their changes to the database; which is not true at all. Bigger functions, such as `CreateCustomerAsync` - which creates a user, and adds roles should be very much concerned with units of work and when to save. By it's own implementation, it's clear that a customer must be created with a role, or not at all.

Comment: Can't you just use the context per request pattern? That handles everything. The context is just available everywhere.

Comment: @usr what context are you talking about?

Comment: One data context or whatever your ORM calls it. Or, one UnitOfWork in your code snippet. Have one of those per request. Share one db connection and one transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider writing a private method for AddCustomerToGroupAsync that does bulk of the work.

```
   private async Task<bool> AddCustomerToGroupInternalAsync(int customerId, int groupId, UnitOfWork uow)
   { ../* All the code in the AddCustomerToGroupAsync inside the unitOfWork */. }
```

For the existing AddCustomerToGroupAsync method, you can open a scope, resolve a unitOfWork and pass it to AddCustomerToGroupInternalAsync method. Similarly for the existing CreateCustomerAsync method, you can pass the UnitOfWork resolved in that method to the AddCustomerToGroupInternalAsync method.

You can call uow.Commit after the call to AddCustomerToGroupInternalAsync  in both cases.